# bower install bootstrap-saas giving ENOTFOUND error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bower-install

I am using the following command:

> bower install bootstrap-saas

However it says 'Package bootstrap-saas not found'

Any solution regarding this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The name is "twitter-bootstrap-sass".

You can find package on http://bower.io/search/ or in bower-cli